# using data.table to flag the first (or last) record in a group

Tags: r, data.table

Given a sortkey, is there a data.table shortcut to duplicate the `first` and `last` functionalities found in SAS and SPSS ?

The pedestrian approach below flags the first record of a group.

Given the elegance of data.table (with which I'm slowly getting familiar), I'm assuming there's a shortcut using a self join & `mult`, but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Here's the example:

```
require(data.table)

set.seed(123)
n <- 17
DT <- data.table(x=sample(letters[1:3],n,replace=T),
                 y=sample(LETTERS[1:3],n,replace=T))
sortkey  <- c("x","y")
setkeyv(DT,sortkey)
key <- paste(DT$x,DT$y,sep="-")
nw <- c( T , key[2:n]!=key[1:(n-1)] )
DT$first <- 1*nw
DT
```

Comment: good answers here including a data.table solution: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/fast-ways-in-r-to-get-the-first-row-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-an-identifier/7889#7889

Comment: I think the M.Dimo specifically wants to *label* the first and last in the group rather than *extract* them. The link you pointed to, as well as the `mult` approach the OP is referring to, show how to *extract*, not *label*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are couple of solutions using `data.table`:

```
## Option 1 (cleaner solution, added 2016-11-29)
uDT <- unique(DT)
DT[, c("first","last"):=0L]
DT[uDT, first:=1L, mult="first"]
DT[uDT, last:=1L, mult="last"]


## Option 2 (original answer, retained for posterity)
DT <- cbind(DT, first=0L, last=0L)
DT[DT[unique(DT),,mult="first", which=TRUE], first:=1L]
DT[DT[unique(DT),,mult="last", which=TRUE], last:=1L]

head(DT)
#      x y first last
# [1,] a A     1    1
# [2,] a B     1    1
# [3,] a C     1    0
# [4,] a C     0    1
# [5,] b A     1    1
# [6,] b B     1    1
```

There's obviously a lot packed into each of those lines. The key construct, though, is the following, which returns the row index of the first record in each group:

```
DT[unique(DT),,mult="first", which=TRUE]
# [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7 11 13 15
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a sense this was possible using the join & "first" , but couldn't figure out the right syntax. There it is, clearly explained. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. In practice, I'd actually probably use something like @PrasadChalasani's approach. But I thought this was a nice demo of a bunch of `data.table`'s features and hoped some others might find it useful. I'll also be interested to learn (a) if there's a better data.table solution for this, and (b) if there's a better way than `unique(DT)` of extracting all unique key combinations in the `data.table`.

Comment: @Josh a) can't think of one, you're spot on b) no, `unique.data.table` is very fast by not using `paste` under the hood, so can't think of anything better. Another option is to use `list` columns to store the vector results for each group, rather than an atomic column which repeats all the group names over and over. To create such a table use list of list in `j` e.g. `ans=DT[,list(listcol=list(cumprod(v)),by=x]`. The result is then just one row per group. First item of each group's result is then : `ans[,sapply(listcol,"[",1)]`.

Comment: And I like @Prasad's approach too. +1.

Comment: An alternative: `DT[DT[,.N,by=list(x,y)][,cumsum(N)],last:=1]` and  `DT[DT[,.N,by=list(x,y)][,cumsum(N)-N+1],first:=1]`

Comment: This will no longer work as unique(DT) returns a partial DT with the unique elements, not a boolean vector indicating which values are unique. Using duplicated, and then !duplicated could work, but then one might simply go for Prasad Chalasani's solution, which is simpler.

Answer (score 10):

One easy way is to use the `duplicated()` function. When applied to a data-frame, it produces a vector where an entry is TRUE if and only if the row value combination has not occurred before, when moving down the data-frame.

```
DT$first <- !duplicated( DT[, list(x,y) ])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
DT$last <- rev(!duplicated( DT[, list(rev(x),rev(y)) ]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

> DT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       x y first  last                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [1,] a A  TRUE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [2,] a B  TRUE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [3,] a C  TRUE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [4,] a C FALSE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [5,] b A  TRUE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [6,] b B  TRUE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [7,] b C  TRUE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [8,] b C FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [9,] b C FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [10,] b C FALSE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [11,] c A  TRUE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [12,] c A FALSE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [13,] c B  TRUE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [14,] c B FALSE  TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [15,] c C  TRUE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [16,] c C FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [17,] c C FALSE  TRUE
```

Another way without using `duplicated()` is:

```
DT[ unique(DT), list(first = c(1, rep(0,length(y)-1)),                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                     last =  c(rep(0,length(y)-1),1 )) ]      

      x y  first last                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  [1,] a A     1    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [2,] a B     1    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [3,] a C     1    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [4,] a C     0    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [5,] b A     1    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [6,] b B     1    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [7,] b C     1    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [8,] b C     0    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [9,] b C     0    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [10,] b C     0    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [11,] c A     1    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [12,] c A     0    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [13,] c B     1    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [14,] c B     0    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [15,] c C     1    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [16,] c C     0    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [17,] c C     0    1
```

Comment: Thanks! Still wondering about a data.table solution, but elegance definitely qualifies in this case.

Comment: You're welcome... I just added another way to do it. The `mult` feature you're referring to is only for picking either the first or last (or all) matches when there are multiple matches to the `i` argument in `DT[i,j,mult=... ]`

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to use `unique`

```
DT <- data.table(
    x=sample(letters[1:3],n,replace=T),
    y=sample(LETTERS[1:3],n,replace=T)
)
# keep first duplicate
unique(DT, by = c("x", "y"))
# keep last duplicate
unique(DT, by = c("x", "y"), fromLast = T)
```