# Use of lapply .SD in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I am not very clear about use of `.SD` and `by`.

For instance, does the below snippet mean: 'change all the columns in `DT` to factor except `A` and `B`?' It also says in `data.table` manual: "`.SD` refers to the Subset of the `data.table` for each group (excluding the grouping columns)" - so columns `A` and `B` are excluded?

```
DT = DT[ ,lapply(.SD, as.factor), by=.(A,B)]
```

However, I also read that `by` means like 'group by' in SQL when you do aggregation. For instance, if I would like to sum (like `colsum` in SQL) over all the columns except `A` and `B` do I still use something similar? Or in this case, does the below code mean to take the sum and group by values in columns `A` and `B`? (take sum and group by `A,B` as in SQL)

```
DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=.(A,B)]
```

Then how do I do a simple `colsum` over all the columns except `A` and `B`?

Comment: `DT[,colSums(.SD),.SDcols=-c(A, B)]` or `DT[,lapply(.SD, sum),.SDcols=-c(A, B)]`

Comment: Using `by` means that within each `A`x`B` pairing, you sum the value of every _other_ column in `DT`. @Khashaa's comment is (a few of the ways ) how to sum over all columns excepting `A` and `B`, _not by group_

Comment: @MichaelChirico,When I change the column type though as in the first example, `by` means exclude I guess, right?  and which one is faster? `colSums` or `lapply` ?

Comment: `by` does not mean exclude. It's just that the value of .SD refers only to other columns when `by` is used (which is a strange rule, I think). Regarding `colSums`, don't use it, as mentioned at the bottom here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts

Comment: @Frank nice reference on `colSums`, however I'm curious which is faster if you're _not_ doing it by group, but rather over the whole table.

Comment: I think the most natural way if you're summing over the whole table (except two cols) is `sapply( DT[, !c("A","B"), with=FALSE], sum)`. You say you tried the three methods... what did you find?

Comment: @Frank Is that because `sum` is internally optimized? (explained at length by @Arun here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31854111/3573401)

Comment: @Khashaa Oh, maybe I'm wrong then, if data.table has some magic super-performant sum that only works in `j`... in which case Michael's answers below should be better.

Comment: @Frank So I tried these three methods. IV is my data table with 100M rows and I am taking sum over 26 columns. vector m includes these 26 columns that I am interested in.   1) `colSums(IV[ , 3:28, with=F])` ; 2)`IV[ , colSums(.SD) , .SDcols=m]` ; 3) `IV[,lapply(.SD,sum),.SDcols=m]` .  So number 2 and 3 are sort of comparable in terms of speed (however, number 3 with `lapply` is the slowest). Number 1 is very  fast though. Do you think it is because in numbers 2 and 3, it does some kind of a for loop? especially `lapply`?

Comment: I also noticed that when I use `lapply` to convert multiple columns to `factor`, it is very slow compared to updating each column line by line  using `:=` .

Comment: @KTY I'm not sure about why your benchmark turned out that way. Maybe Michael can add that to his benchmark test below. Regarding conversion of multiple columns to factor, you could consider `set` in a loop, mentioned in my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just to illustrate the comments above with an example, let's take

```
set.seed(10238)
# A and B are the "id" variables within which the
#   "data" variables C and D vary meaningfully
DT = data.table(
  A = rep(1:3, each = 5L), 
  B = rep(1:5, 3L),
  C = sample(15L),
  D = sample(15L)
)
DT
#     A B  C  D
#  1: 1 1 14 11
#  2: 1 2  3  8
#  3: 1 3 15  1
#  4: 1 4  1 14
#  5: 1 5  5  9
#  6: 2 1  7 13
#  7: 2 2  2 12
#  8: 2 3  8  6
#  9: 2 4  9 15
# 10: 2 5  4  3
# 11: 3 1  6  5
# 12: 3 2 12 10
# 13: 3 3 10  4
# 14: 3 4 13  7
# 15: 3 5 11  2
```

Compare the following:

```
#Sum all columns
DT[ , lapply(.SD, sum)]
#     A  B   C   D
# 1: 30 45 120 120

#Sum all columns EXCEPT A, grouping BY A
DT[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = A]
#    A  B  C  D
# 1: 1 15 38 43
# 2: 2 15 30 49
# 3: 3 15 52 28

#Sum all columns EXCEPT A
DT[ , lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = !"A"]
#     B   C   D
# 1: 45 120 120

#Sum all columns EXCEPT A, grouping BY B
DT[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = B, .SDcols = !"A"]
#    B  C  D
# 1: 1 27 29
# 2: 2 17 30
# 3: 3 33 11
# 4: 4 23 36
# 5: 5 20 14
```

A few notes:

- You said "does the below snippet... change all the columns in `DT`..."

The answer is *no*, and this is very important for `data.table`. The object returned is a *new* `data.table`, and all of the columns in `DT` are exactly as they were before running the code.

- You mentioned wanting to change the column types

Referring to the point above again, note that your code (`DT[ , lapply(.SD, as.factor)]`) returns a *new* `data.table` and does not change `DT` at all. One (**incorrect**) way to do this, which is done with `data.frame`s in `base`, is to overwrite the old `data.table` with the new `data.table` you've returned, i.e., `DT = DT[ , lapply(.SD, as.factor)]`.

This is wasteful because it involves creating copies of `DT` which can be an efficiency killer when `DT` is large. The correct `data.table` approach to this problem is to update the columns by reference using`` `:=` ``, e.g., `DT[ , names(DT) := lapply(.SD, as.factor)]`, which creates no copies of your data. See [`data.table`'s reference semantics vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) for more on this.

- You mentioned comparing efficiency of `lapply(.SD, sum)` to that of `colSums`. `sum` is internally optimized in `data.table` (you can note this is true from the output of adding the `verbose = TRUE` argument within `[]`); to see this in action, let's beef up your `DT` a bit and run a benchmark:

Results:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(12039)
nn = 1e7; kk = seq(100L)
DT = setDT(replicate(26L, sample(kk, nn, TRUE), simplify=FALSE))
DT[ , LETTERS[1:2] := .(sample(100L, nn, TRUE), sample(100L, nn, TRUE))]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  times = 100L,
  colsums = colSums(DT[ , !c("A", "B")]),
  lapplys = DT[ , lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = !c("A", "B")]
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  colsums 1624.2622 2020.9064 2028.9546 2034.3191 2049.9902 2140.8962   100
#  lapplys  246.5824  250.3753  252.9603  252.1586  254.8297  266.1771   100
```

Comment: A `for` loop with `set` is another option for converting a large number of columns, mentioned at the bottom of this answer and suggested/endorsed by Arun and Matt: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/1191259

Comment: @Frank yes, and that's what I do now, but it took me quite some time to wrap my head around what was going on there. But it's great to be exposed to that early.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, thanks for the tip on changing the column types without creating a new DT! very helpful.