# Collapse and aggregate several row values by date

Tags: r

I've got a data set that looks like this:

```
date, location, value, tally, score
2016-06-30T09:30Z, home, foo, 1,
2016-06-30T12:30Z, work, foo, 2,
2016-06-30T19:30Z, home, bar, , 5
```

I need to aggregate these rows together, to obtain a result such as:

```
date, location, value, tally, score
2016-06-30, [home, work], [foor, bar], 3, 5
```

There are several challenges for me:

- The resulting row (a daily aggregate) must include the rows for this day (2016-06-30 in my above example
- Some rows (strings) will result in an array containing all the values present on this day
- Some others (ints) will result in a sum

I've had a look at `dplyr`, and if possible I'd like to do this in R.

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit:

Here's a `dput` of the data

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2016-06-30T09:30Z", 
"2016-06-30T12:30Z", "2016-06-30T19:30Z"), class = "factor"), 
    location = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("home", "work"
    ), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("bar", 
    "foo"), class = "factor"), tally = c(1L, 2L, NA), score = c(NA, 
    NA, 5L)), .Names = c("date", "location", "value", "tally", 
"score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: @Hack-R: oops sorry! I amended my question with a dput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydat<-structure(list(date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2016-06-30T09:30Z", 
                                                       "2016-06-30T12:30Z", "2016-06-30T19:30Z"), class = "factor"), 
                      location = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("home", "work"
                      ), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("bar", 
                                                                                        "foo"), class = "factor"), tally = c(1L, 2L, NA), score = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                    NA, 5L)), .Names = c("date", "location", "value", "tally", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

mydat$date <- as.Date(mydat$date)

require(data.table)
mydat.dt <- data.table(mydat)
mydat.dt <- mydat.dt[, lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse=" "), by = date]

cbind(mydat.dt, aggregate(mydat[,c("tally", "score")], by=list(mydat$date), FUN = sum, na.rm=T)[2:3])
```

which gives you:

```
         date       location       value tally score
1: 2016-06-30 home work home foo foo bar     3     5
```

Note that if you wanted to you could probably do it all in one step in the reshaping of the `data.table` but I found this to be a quicker and easier way for me to achieve the same thing in 2 steps.

Comment: Thank you. I found some helpful information to understand `lapply` and `.SD` [in this separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276887/use-of-lapply-sd-in-data-table-r).

Comment: @basbabybel Happy to help