# How to apply a function to a subset of data.table using by and exposing all columns to the function?

Tags: r, data.table

When slicing a `data.table` by group(s), variables used to slice the data are not in the subset during the function execution. I demonstrate this using `debugonce`.

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = rep(letters[1:4], each = 3), b = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 6), c = rnorm(12))

myfun <- function(y) paste(y$a, y$b, y$c, collapse = "")

> debugonce(myfun)
> x[, myfun(.SD), by = .(b, a)]
debugging in: myfun(.SD)
debug: paste(y$a, y$b, y$c, collapse = "")
Browse[2]> y
            c
1: -1.2662416
2:  0.9818497
3: -0.5395385
```

What I'm after is the functionality of the split-sapply paradigm, where I would slice a data.frame according to factor(s) and apply the function to all columns, that is, also including the variables which have been used to slice it (demonstrated below).

```
> debugonce(myfun)

> sapply(split(x, f = list(x$b, x$a)), FUN = myfun)
debugging in: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
debug: paste(y$a, y$b, y$c, collapse = "")
Browse[2]> y
a b          c
1: a a -1.2662416
2: a a  0.9818497
3: a a -0.5395385
```

Comment: [This comment by Matt Dowle on a question regarding `.SD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r#comment10533466_8509301) shows an alternative to use debugging: `x[, print(.SD), by = .(b, a)]`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The OP has a function which takes a list as argument which should contain *all* columns of the data.table including the columns used for grouping in `by`.

According to `help(".SD")`:

> `.SD` is a data.table containing the Subset of `x`'s Data for each group, **excluding** any columns used in `by` (or `keyby`).

(emphasis mine)

> `.BY` is a list containing a length 1 vector for each item in `by`. This can be useful when `by` is not known in advance.

So, `.BY` and `.SD` complement each other to access all columns of the data.table.

Instead of explicitely repeating the `by` columns in the function call

```
x[, myfun(c(list(b, a), .SD)), by = .(b, a)]
```

we can use

```
x[, myfun(c(.BY, .SD)), by = .(b, a)]
```

> ```
>    b a                                                                 V1
> 1: a a    a a -1.02091215130492a a -0.295107569536843a a 0.77776326093429
> 2: a b b a -0.369037832486311b a -0.716211663822323b a -0.264799143319049
> 3: b c      c b -1.39603530693486c b 1.4707902839894c b 0.721925347069227
> 4: b d   d b -1.15220308230505d b -0.736782242593426d b 0.420986999145651
> ```

The OP has used `debugonce()` to show the argument passed to `myfun()`:

```
> debugonce(myfun)
> x[, myfun(c(.BY, .SD)), by = .(b, a)]
debugging in: myfun(c(.BY, .SD))
debug at #1: paste(y$a, y$b, y$c, collapse = "")
Browse[2]> y
$b
[1] "a"

$a
[1] "a"

$c
[1] -1.0209122 -0.2951076  0.7777633
```

---

#### Another example

With another sample data set and function it might be easier to exemplify the core of the question:

```
x <- data.table(a = rep(letters[3:6], each = 3), b = rep(c("x", "y"), each = 6), c = 1:12)
myfun <- function(y) paste(y$a, y$b, y$c, sep = "/", collapse = "-")

x[, myfun(.SD), by = .(b, a)]
```

> ```
>    b a             V1
> 1: x c    //1-//2-//3
> 2: x d    //4-//5-//6
> 3: y e    //7-//8-//9
> 4: y f //10-//11-//12
> ```

So, columns `b`and `a` do appear in the output as grouping variables but they aren't passed via `.SD` to the function.

Now, with `.BY` complementing `.SD`

```
x[, myfun(c(.BY, .SD)), by = .(b, a)]
```

> ```
>    b a                   V1
> 1: x c    c/x/1-c/x/2-c/x/3
> 2: x d    d/x/4-d/x/5-d/x/6
> 3: y e    e/y/7-e/y/8-e/y/9
> 4: y f f/y/10-f/y/11-f/y/12
> ```

all columns of the data.table are passed to the function.

#### Separate arguments in the function call

[Roland has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295639/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-subset-of-data-table-using-by-and-exposing-all-colu/45295654?noredirect=1#comment77599900_45295654) to pass `.BY` and `.SD` as separate parameters to the function. Indeed, `.BY` is a list object and `.SD` is a data.table object (which essentially is also a list which allowed us to use `c(.BY, .SD)`). There might be cases where the difference might matter.

To verify, we can define a function which prints `str()` as a side effect. The function is only called for the first group (`.GRP == 1L`).

```
myfun1 <- function(y) str(y)
x[, if (.GRP == 1L) myfun1(.SD), by = .(b, a)]
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
>  $ c: int  1 2 3
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  - attr(*, ".data.table.locked")= logi TRUE
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: b,a
> ```

```
x[, if (.GRP == 1L) myfun1(.BY), by = .(b, a)]
```

> ```
> List of 2
>  $ b: chr "x"
>  $ a: chr "c"
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: b,a
> ```

```
x[, if (.GRP == 1L) myfun1(c(.BY, .SD)), by = .(b, a)]
```

> ```
> List of 3
>  $ b: chr "x"
>  $ a: chr "c"
>  $ c: int [1:3] 1 2 3
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: b,a
> ```

#### Additional links

Beside `help(".SD")` the comments & answers to the following SO questions might by useful:

- [What does .SD stand for in data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r)
- [Use of lapply .SD in data.table R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276887/use-of-lapply-sd-in-data-table-r)

Comment: Note that this answer only works because `myfun` accepts a list. I would modify the function and pass `.BY` and `.SD` as separate parameters.

Comment: @Roland `myfun` was defined by the OP to process _all_ columns of the data.table, so it purposefully takes a list argument. I agree that it would be cleaner to pass `.SD` and `.BY` separately.

Comment: @Roland I've added a section on separate parameters.