# Rolling over function with 2 vector arguments

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, xts

I want to apply rolling on the function that requires 2 vector arguments. Here is the exmample (that doesn't work) using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(cbind.data.frame(x=1:100, y=101:200))
my_sum <- function(x, y) {
  x <- log(x)
  y <- x * y
  return(x + y)
}
roll_df <- frollapply(df, 10, function(x, y) {
  my_sum(x, y)})
```

It doesn't recognize y column. Ofc, the solution can be using xts or some other package.

EDIT:
This is the real function I want to apply:

```
library(dpseg)
dpseg_roll <- function(time, price) {
  p <- estimateP(x=time, y=price, plot=FALSE)
  segs <- dpseg(time, price, jumps=jumps, P=p, type=type, store.matrix=TRUE)
  slope_last <- segs$segments$slope[length(segs$segments$slope)]
  return(slope_last)
}
```

Comment: just as a small comment, you can also initiate your data.table like this: data.table(x=1:100, y=101:200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) you can apply any function in rolling window. Running window can be created also on a rows of data.frame inserted to `x` argument. Let's focus on simpler function `my_sum`. Argument `f` in runner can accept only one object (`data` in this case). I encourage to put `browser()` to the function to debug row-by-row before you apply some fancy model on the subset (some algorithms requires some minimal number of observations).

```r
my_sum <- function(data) {
  # browser()
  x <- log(data$x)
  y <- x * data$y
  tail(x + y, 1) # return only one value
}
```

`my_sum` should return only one value, because `runner` computes for each row - if `my_sum` returns vector, you would get a list.
Because runner is an independent function you need to pass data.table object to `x`. Best way to do this is to use `x = .SD` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295639/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-subset-of-data-table-using-by-and-exposing-all-colu/45295654) why)

```r
df[, 
   new_col := runner(
      x = .SD,
      f = my_sum,
      k = 10
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are going to do with `frollapply` (`mean` or `sum` or something else?).

Assuming you are about to use rolling sum, here might be one example. I rewrote your function `my_sum` such that it applies to `df` directly.

```
my_sum <- function(...) {
  v <- c(...)
  x <- log(v[[1]])
  y <- Reduce(`*`,v)
  return(x + y)
}

roll_df <- frollapply(
  my_sum(df), 
  10,
  FUN = sum)
```

Comment: In my example, it returns an list with 2 elements?

Comment: I change into: add real function I want to apply.

Answer (score 0):

`rollapply` in zoo passes a zoo object to the function to be applied if `coredata=FALSE` is used.  The zoo object is made up of a time and a value part so we can use the following if the x value represents ascending values (which I gather it does).  Note that `my_sum` in the question returns a 10 element result if the two arguments are length 10 so `out` shown below is a 100 x 10 zoo object with the first 9 rows filled with NAs.

If you don't want the NAs omit `fill=NA` or if you want to apply the function to partial inputs at the beginning instead of `fill=NA` use `partial=TRUE`. If you only want one of the 10 elements, such as the last one, then use `function(x) my_sum(time(x), coredata(x))[10]` in place of the function shown or just use `out[, 10]`.

`fortify.zoo(out)` can be used to turn a zoo object `out` to a data frame if you need the result in that form or use `as.data.frame(out)` if you want to drop the times. `as.data.table(out)` also works in a similar manner.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df)  # df$x becomes the time part and df$y the value part
out <- rollapplyr(z, 10, function(u) my_sum(time(u), coredata(u)), 
  coredata = FALSE, fill = NA)

dim(out)
## [1] 100  10
```

Note that in `dpseg_roll` that `jumps` and `type` are not defined.