# Finding number of NA in multiple columns by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set of different cities and the different sports teams they have:

```
**City**    **Basketball**  **Soccer**    **Tennis**    **Football**
   AA         Titans          Astros       Royals         Eagles
   AA         Crimson           NA         Falcons        Packers
   AA           NA            Phoenix      Tigers           NA
   AA         Goblins           NA         Lions            NA
   BB           NA              NA           NA             NA
   BB         Bears           Rockets      Broncos          NA
   CC         Pelicans        Wildfires    Panthers         NA
   CC           NA            Bobcats      Blizzard         NA
   CC           NA              NA         Tornadoes        NA
   CC           NA              NA         Hurricanes       NA
```

I want to group the data by city and find the total number of NAs for each columnn for each city. How would I go about doing this? I've tried this after doing some research

```
aggregate(df[,2:4], by=list(df$City), colSums(is.na(df)))
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R is your enemy here.

`data.table` is friendlier:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # <- convert to data.table
# going column-by-column, count NA
df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), by = City]
```

See [Getting Started with `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started), a [primer on `.SD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276887/use-of-lapply-sd-in-data-table-r/32277135#32277135), and [this on the use of `lapply(.SD,...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32277135/3576984) for more.

Note well that the use of `colSums` necessitates converting your `data.frame` to a `matrix`, which will force all the columns to have the same class (here, `character`) if they don't already, which can be costly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `aggregate` syntax was a bit off.  Use a correct custom anonymous function and it should work:

```
aggregate(df[,2:4], by=list(df$City), FUN=function(x) { sum(is.na(x)) })
```

### Demo