# select only rows with max value over group of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with ~ 100 mln rows, some kind of that DT

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(3,2,1,7,6,5), 
                 b = c("1","1","1","2","2","2"), 
                 c = c("2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
                 d = c(5,6,7,8,9,0))
```

For select only rows with max value over group (b,c), I use

```
DT[DT[, .I[which.max(a)], by = list(b,c)]$V1]
```

which gives

```
   a b c d
1: 3 1 2 5
2: 7 2 3 8
```

It works fine, but my question is maybe it's not a faster/optimal solution.
Any advices are welcome!

Comment: ok, i'll add an iformation about perfomance

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852294/how-to-speed-up-subset-by-groups)

Comment: @DavidArenburg should i mark my question as duplicate, i've missed this post, it hepls me a lot! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `order`.  We group by 'b', 'c' columns, `order` the rows based on the 'a' values in increasing order and get the last row using `tail`

```
DT[order(a), tail(.SD, 1) , .(b, c)]
```

or with `setorder`

```
setorder(DT, a)[, tail(.SD, 1), .(b, c)]
```

Comment: In documentation said, that you should avoid .SD for faster solution, but I'll try your's

Comment: @Shin That is true, but in your function, you are also using `which.max`