# How do I flag the last observation in a group while maintaining a specific sort order within the group?

Tags: r, data.table

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474456/2766558). I have data like this:

```
   x t
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 1 3
4: 2 1
5: 2 2
6: 2 3
```

I'd like to flag the last observation in every group (and keep the other observations), defined by `x`, where the "last" observation is defined by `t`. I tried this:

```
dt[order(x, t), flag_last := 1, by = "x", mult = "last"]
```

but that returns

```
   x t flag_last
1: 1 1         1
2: 1 2         1
3: 1 3         1
4: 2 1         1
5: 2 2         1
6: 2 3         1
```

The desired output is

```
   x t flag_last
1: 1 1         0
2: 1 2         0
3: 1 3         1
4: 2 1         0
5: 2 2         0
6: 2 3         1
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

---

A couple of caveats:

- The actual dataset is roughly 61 GB and there are only a couple of observations per `x` group, so if possible I'd like to avoid creating another copy with the unique values or creating another copy with dplyr. If that's unavoidable, I'll make do.
- Obviously this is simple data. **The number of observations within each group is not necessarily the same**, and the values for `t` differ too, so simply picking out `t == 3` will not work.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oops, left that part out. I added it to the question.

Comment: OK, I have a feeling this is probably an XY problem (as I don't really see any use for such a variable), but I would go about this as follows `dt[dt[, .I[.N], by = x]$V1, flag := 1]`. A bit less memory efficient (and probably slower) could be `dt[, flag := c(rep(0, .N - 1), 1), by = x]`

Comment: Maybe just `df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(flag_last = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 1L,0L))`  Or `df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(flag_last = ifelse(row_number() == max(t), 1L,0L))
`

Comment: Another cool option could also be `dt[attr(grouping(x), "ends"), falg := 1]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg isn't `grouping()` still something experimental?

Comment: @sindri_baldur its in the stable versions so I guess not...

Comment: Your extension of the linked question has a mistake -- `order(...)` is an integer vector of row numbers, so the `mult=`  used by Josh doesn't apply here. You need to use a data.table `dt[udt, on="x", mult="last", flag := 1]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg it should probably be `dt[dt[, .I[which.max(t)], by = "x"]$V1, flag_last := 1L]`

Comment: @Alexis Yeah I've already posted this in comments in one of answers. It wasn't clear to me at first that they want the maximum value rather the last value in the group.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in `.I` like this:

```
DT[, is.end := .I == last(.I), by = "x"]
```

Comment: How does this incorporate t? The data aren't sorted by t by default

Comment: How is t involved at all?  Is the "last observation" not the last?  Please clarify if not.  If what you meant was to flag the largest `t` in each group rather than the last t in each group then use `t == max(t)`

Comment: Guess they want the observation with the maximum `t`. Something like  `as.integer(t==max(t))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[, flag_last := replace(vector(mode = "integer", length = .N), which.max(t), 1L), x]


#    x t flag_last
# 1: 1 1         0
# 2: 1 2         0
# 3: 1 3         1
# 4: 2 1         0
# 5: 2 2         0
# 6: 2 3         1
```

Comment: What about a simple `as.integer(t==max(t))` instead?

Comment: @nicola I think that would be slightly less efficient. Would be cool if someone did benchmark on Yuge data

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `.N` and `which.max` to check for equality between the row index and the row index at which t is maximized

```
df[, flag := as.integer(1:.N == which.max(t)), x]
```

But benchmarking shows `replace` is faster on my machine for this dataset, and if you don't mind NAs instead of 0s, David Arenburg's suggested method using `.I` is fastest.

```
df <- data.table(x = rep(1:1e4, each = 1e4), t = sample(1e4*1e4))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
replace = df[, flag_last := replace(vector(mode = "integer", length = .N), which.max(t), 1L), x],
use.N = df[, flag := as.integer(1:.N == which.max(t)), x],
use.max = df[, flag := as.integer(t==max(t)), x],
use.I = {
  df[, flag := 0L]
  df[df[, .I[which.max(t)], by = x]$V1, flag := 1L]
},
use.I.no0 = df[df[, .I[which.max(t)], by = x]$V1, flag := 1L],
times = 20)


# Unit: seconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#    replace 1.228490 1.292348 1.442919 1.443021 1.578300 1.659990    20  b 
#      use.N 1.439939 1.522782 1.617104 1.574932 1.696046 1.923207    20   c
#    use.max 1.405741 1.436817 1.596363 1.502337 1.663895 2.743942    20   c
#      use.I 1.497599 1.547276 1.574657 1.564789 1.589066 1.686353    20  bc
#  use.I.no0 1.080715 1.115329 1.162752 1.145145 1.182280 1.383989    20 a
```

Comment: Try comparing to `dt[dt[, .I[which.max(t)], by = x]$V1, flag := 1]`

Comment: I've added that method. The other methods set non-1 values to 0 rather than NA, so I've modified your method to match the output of the others.

Comment: @Frank it looks like that question answers how to create an indicator for the last row. While that appeared to be the question here too,  Michael A appears to indicate in response to G. Grothendieck they actually want an indicator for the max value of `t`. There's probably a dupe for that question somewhere too though.

Comment: I kind of doubt the zero vs NA matters as only the location of the last value is what OP looking for, but what ever.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick, if you create an id variable that you can then use to merge the two datasets together:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
t <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
id <- as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

data <- data.frame(x,t, id)
```

You create a sliced dataset with the max value of each group, and then you merge it back to the initial dataframe.

```
sliced <- data %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  slice(which.max(t)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id) %>%
  mutate(max = "max_group")

tot <- left_join(data, sliced, c("id"))
```

The sliced df has only two variables, so might be not too bad to work with. This is the easier way that came to my mind.